# Trust anchor for certification path not found. Android Compose Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ssl-certificate, retrofit

network-security-config file :

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>>
</domain-config>

<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">12.123.123.123</domain>
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="@raw/my_ca" />
            </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

i have my_ca.pem file in raw folder

Manifest file :

```
  <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
/>
```

still i have error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.